# laravel get insertGetId value without inserting id

Tags: laravel

My database column is given below

```
 - id AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
 - message VARCHAR(100)

     $id = Message::insertGetId(array(

         'message' => 'test message',

     ));

     echo $id
```

and `$id` doesn't has any value.

How can I get the inserted id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem in other method and here is my solution:

```
$message = Message::create(array(

     'message' => 'test message',

 ));

 echo $message->id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use laravel eloquent. Try like bellow:

```
  $message = Message::all();
  print_r($message);
```